# Tool that allows users to login to an app that I've created?

Tags: html, css, html-editor, login

So, I've created a web app in HTML and CSS. I want users to pay for the use of this app, and then be able to log in to it. This tool must have specific features:

1. Users must be able to create their accounts online,
2. Users must then be able to log-in on my HTML/CSS app.
3. It must look good (i.e. not plain text on a plain background).

I remember seeing a YouTube advert for one like this. It featured a man coding his own software and taking him 90 days, and with this new app he gets it done in 3. Any ideas?

Comment: Offline? It you don't go to a server, then anyone can press F12, copy your code, cut out the login code and open what's left in a new browser tab. I think that you have a problem (look into Web Assembly).